# Autocomplete edit text no funciona con acentos

Tags: java, android, edittext

Tengo un autocomplete edit text pero no hace match entre palabras sin y con acento, quisiera que al poner alguna palabra sin acento me devuelva las opciones que coincidan aunque lleven acento

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio tocho2301, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado e investigado, saludos!

Comment: Debes agregar un custom filter, pero para esto debes agregar información a tu pregunta, revisar [ask].

Answer (score 0):

En java tienes el normalizer que convierte tu string con acentos a uno sin acentos, como usarlo te lo adjunto aquí:

```
string = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
string = string.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

de forma que en string pongas lo que quieres normalizar para que autocomplete sin acentos.

Comment: El "autocomplete" de un EditText no funciona al teclear palabras acentuadas, esto no tendría que ver con la pregunta.

Comment: @Elenasys si pasas el string que se pone en el EditText por el normalizer le quitará los acentos y podrá autocompletar